# Angular5 continuous navigation

Tags: angular, routes

I am new to Angular (been developing in angularjs for a few years now). I have been given as task and I am unsure how to approach it, so I thought I would ask here.
I have been tasked with creating an application that loads it's states on one page. For example, I would have a home page, 3 steps and a results page.
On the home page there might be a view that has loaded which has a link to step 1, 2 and 3.

If a user clicks step one, then in the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` the first step would load (nothing new there). But if they clicked step 2, I want step 1 to load and then step 2 below it.

The same should happen with step 3 and results.
Similarly, if you were already on the results page and you clicked back or step 1. Instead of loading it, I want it to scroll up to where the view for step 1 is.

I really hope that makes sense.
If it does, can someone help me?

Comment: maybe https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your **home.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf= "step === 1" >
 <app-step-1></spp-step-1>
</div>

<div *ngIf= "step <= 2" >
 <app-step-2></spp-step-2>
</div>

<div *ngIf= "step <= 3" >
 <app-step-3></spp-step-3>
</div>
```

`step` is a variable that you update when you do clicks to navigate through steps.

Comment: Nope. But you can use a querry params and using them you can decide the step variable